# YoutubePlayer that was restored can not play video

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying the `YoutubeApi-Android` sample. I enable the options **"Don't keep Activities"** in **Developer Options**.
While playing video, I return Home, and start the example again. The video can not play. All of the sample: `FragmentDemoActivity`, `PlayerDemoActivity` doens't work.
Seems there are a problem with the instance `YoutubePlayer` was restored by `YoutubePlayerView` and `YoutubePlayerFragment`. `YoutubePlayer` just goes to the state `onVideoStared`, not `onBuffering` and `onPlaying`.

Source code of the example, even if I try to release YoutubePlayer in onDestroy, It's still not working.

```
  public class PlayerViewDemoActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playerview_demo);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
          boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
          player.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
        }
        mPlayer = player;
      }

      @Override
      protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
      }

    @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if(mPlayer != null)
                mPlayer.release();
        }

    }
```

help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I tried to release `YoutubePlayer` before `super.onDestroy()`. It works, although the instance `YoutubePlayer` was still restored on `onInitializationSuccess`.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(mPlayer != null)
            mPlayer.release();
        super.onDestroy();            
    }
```

Don't know why it works.